# SSRS Report Dropdown

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am having SSRS report with Drop down filters Category & Item , but now i want to fill Category Drop down bases on Location Id of user. 
And i can not show filter/drop down to user.

I need to do like when i browse report from asp.net application, i can pass Location Id and based on that Category Drop down need to be filled, how can i do this?

I have tried to fill Category Drop down filter with parameter Location ID but it creates another **Text parameter** in report.

Answer (score 0):

To pass location id i have made "Location ID"  parameter Hidden filter and passed from code while fetching report and Category drop down cascaded properly base on that.